# When show modal using (keyup.enter) from input text, throw Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

im use visual code with angular 4 and bootstrap 4 (v4.alpha, ng-bootstrap).

The problem happens when you finish typing some numbers and pressing enter without losing the focus (to show the modal), is shown modal but in console show the error mentioned. (Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError) and points out that error comes from the input text:

```
    <div class="form-group" 
         [ngClass]="{'has-error': (numeroDocuVar.touched
         ||numeroDocuVar.dirty) && !numeroDocuVar.valid }">
       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                 <input class="form-control" id="numeroDocuId" 
                        type="text" placeholder="Numero documento (requerido)" 
                        [(ngModel)]="IdNumeroDocu" name="numeroDocu"                                                                 
                        #numeroDocuVar="ngModel" 
                     (keyup.enter)="onSearchDocumento(numeroDocuVar.value)"
                        required />
                 <span class="input-group-addon fa fa-search" 
                       (click)="onSearchDocumento(numeroDocuVar.value)" 
                        style="cursor:pointer">
                 </span>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have read that I can do it using ngAfterContentInit, but this variable is not filled by a calculation, it's the user who fills the information in the input text.

I use the ng-bootstrap modal code.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This error isn't shown on production builds... so if worse comes to worst, you could ignore it. It can happen in a lot of different situations though, and changing states / views through user input is definitely a common one.

First thing to do is make sure you're using the Default changeDetection mode and not using 'OnPush' mode. If its your own app that you built and you haven't changed those settings anywhere, you are using the default change detection mode so you're good.

Rather than binding to the keyup event manually in the template, you could wrap the input in an NgForm element and put a submit method in the component code that calls the onSearchDocumento method. This would probably prevent the error and might make for a slightly cleaner template.

```
 <form #formName="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSearchDocumento(formName)">
    ... input and other elements ...
 </form>
```

When you're using NgForm, its submit method automatically listens for the user pressing the enter key. That would pass the contents of the entire form (which in your case would only be one input) as the object named 'formName' and you can access individual form parts with their identifiers, i.e

```
  formName.numeroDocuVar.val
```

If that doesn't work you may have to import ChangeDetectorRef and force it to check changes using its detectChanges() method before proceeding with the rest of the other method. Something like -

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef ... your other imports.... } from '@angular/core'
```

in your component:

```
constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { ...
```

and then add the call to detectChanges in the search method:

```
onSearchDocumento( ... ) { 
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    // rest of method // 
}
```

Comment: Hi diopside!! thanks for your answer, I have tried everything you mention but the error still appears !! If you had another idea, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
For resolve it you should remove focus before you call your modal window.

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}    
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.activeElement, 'blur'); // put this line before you call your modal in the component
this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.modalNotification);
```

Or you should check your inputs like touched at the ngOnInit.

You can read [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. My solution was to manually blur the input before opening the modal:

```
<input 
  ...
  (keyup.enter)="onSearchDocumento($event, numeroDocuVar.value)" 
/>
```

and in the component class (before opening the modal):

```
onSearchDocumento(event, val){
  event.target.blur();
  // ... rest of the method 
}
```